# Breeze.js - Getting both client and server validation errors onto my entity

Tags: validation, breeze

Based on Breeze documentation I have the following solution to add any client side validation errors to a property (`fieldsWithErrors`) on my entity. This works well and I can grab the relevant error to a particular property and apply css classes to indicate validation errors to the user. `episodeManager` is my `EntityManager` and `Reminder` is my entity.

```
episodeManager.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor("Reminder", sr.Reminder, function (entity) {

    entity.fieldsWithErrors = ko.observableArray([]);

    entity.entityAspect.validationErrorsChanged.subscribe(function () {

        entity.fieldsWithErrors.removeAll();

        var errors = entity.entityAspect.getValidationErrors();

        $.each(errors, function () {

            entity.fieldsWithErrors.push(this.propertyName);
        });
    });
});
```

I've added some server side validation in the form of custom .Net attributes (the client side validation errors above are Breeze cloning `[Required]` attributes into rules, I have no custom Breeze validation rules). Any violation of these server-side rules are returned to Breeze in the `fail()` promise after `saveChanges()`. I can't think of a clean way to combine these into my `fieldsWithErrors` entity property alongside any client side errors as if they were all the same. Is there a much simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Breeze v 1.4.0, your server side validation failures should automatically be added to the client side validationResults on a per entity basis, ( in addition to be returned in fail() promise), so you shouldn't have to do anything else.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Nope, not missing a thing. Upgraded to 1.4.0 and there the were. Easiest fix ever :) There's no knockout observable with all the errors though, still need to create my own, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Note that you can keep your custom observable errors in sync by listening to the new EntityManager.validationErrorsChanged event.